# Mocking IQueryable object in TenantDbContext

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, mocking, .net-7.0

Here is my `DbContext` methods:

```
public class TenantDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AspNetUser, AspNetRole, Guid,
    AspNetUserClaim, AspNetUserRole,
    AspNetUserLogin, AspNetRoleClaim,
    AspNetUserToken>
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly IHttpContextData _contextData;
    private readonly IDbUtilities _dbUtilities;
    private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;
    private readonly SeedStatikReferanslar _seedStatikReferanslar;
    private readonly SeedRefTip _seedSystemReferanslar;
    private readonly SeedSysParams _seedSysParams;
    private readonly SeedReferanslar _seedReferanslar;

    public TenantDbContext(DbContextOptions<TenantDbContext> options,
        IMemoryCache memoryCache,
        IHttpContextData contextData,
        SeedStatikReferanslar seedStatikReferanslar,
        IConfiguration configuration,
        IDbUtilities dbUtilities,
        SeedRefTip seedSystemReferanslar,
        SeedSysParams seedSysParams,
        SeedReferanslar seedReferanslar,
        bool DoNotSeedDB  = false) : base(options)
    {
        _memoryCache = memoryCache;
        _contextData = contextData;
        _seedStatikReferanslar = seedStatikReferanslar;
        _configuration = configuration;
        _dbUtilities = dbUtilities;
        _seedSystemReferanslar = seedSystemReferanslar;
        _seedSysParams = seedSysParams;
        _seedReferanslar = seedReferanslar;
        DoNotSeed = DoNotSeedDB;
    } 
      {
       public virtual DbSet<Stok> Stok { get; set; } //(and more DbSet)
      }
    }
```

Here are my  Repository samples:

```
public class StokRepository : AsyncRepository<Stok>, IStokRepository
{
    private readonly TenantDbContext _tenantDbContext;
    public StokRepository(TenantDbContext dbContext) : base(dbContext)
    {
        _tenantDbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public async Task<Stok> GetByIdAsync(Guid Id, bool withRelationalTables = false, bool withReferences = false)
    {
        var query = _tenantDbContext.Stok.Where(x => x.Id == Id);//I want setup this 

        if (withRelationalTables)
        {
            query = query
                .Include(x => x.StokNotlar)
                .Include(x => x.StokTeminler).ThenInclude(x => x.CariHesap)
                .Include(x => x.StokFiyat)
                .Include(x => x.StokMuhasebe)
                .Include(x => x.StokBirimler).ThenInclude(x => x.BirimBarkods)
                .Include(x => x.GTIP);
        }

        Stok stok = await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        if (stok == null)
            return null;

        if (withReferences)
            await MatchStokWithReferans(new List<Stok> { stok });

        stok = (await GetAllStokWithSanalSahalarAsync(new List<Stok> { stok })).FirstOrDefault();

        return stok;
}
```

i want to setup :

```
 var query = _tenantDbContext.Stok.Where(x => x.Id == Id);
```

my test method:

```
        [Fact]
        public async void StokRepoTest()
        {
            IQueryable<Stok> data = new List<Stok>()
            {
              new Stok()
              {
               Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
               MalKodu  = "abc"
            }}.AsQueryable();

            var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Stok>>();
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<Stok>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<Stok>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<Stok>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<Stok>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

            var contextMock = new Mock<TenantDbContext>
            (
             new DbContextOptions<TenantDbContext>(),
             null,
             null,
             null,
             null,
             null,
             null,
             null,
             null,
             false);
            contextMock.Setup(x => x.Stok)
                       .Returns(mockSet.Object);

            StokRepository stokRepository = new StokRepository(contextMock.Object);

            var stok = await stokRepository.GetByIdAsync(Guid.NewGuid(), false, false);

            Assert.NotNull(stok);
        }
```

The error message that is returned while :

```
The provider for the source 'IQueryable' doesn't implement 'IAsyncQueryProvider'. Only providers that implement 'IAsyncQueryProvider' can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to override members of your class, you need to use the `virtual` keyword. So try to change to:

```
public virtual DbSet<Stok> Stok { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks.This solution worked. But I got another error.  : 'The provider for the source 'IQueryable' doesn't implement 'IAsyncQueryProvider'. Only providers that implement 'IAsyncQueryProvider' can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations '

Comment: That's because you're using FirstOrDefaultAsync(), but you don't need to. Just use FirstOrDefault() and don't need to await. Just in rare cases you need to perform an async operation on your DB. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: @RicardoAlexandre You should never recommend against using `FirstOrDefaultAsync`, that just shows the way you are testing is bad.

Comment: @DavidG oh, I didn't recommend against. I said that he doesn't need to. If he wishes the code to run, he could try using `FirstOrDefault`. The Microsoft itself gives examples when async is usefull, but it's not always the best practice. But of course, if he absolutely need it... Why would you always recommend using FirstOrDefaultAsync, tho?

Comment: There is almost no reason to not use the async methods

Comment: @DavidG  
I want to use async programming. How can I do that. ? The methods I found don't work.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to mock the context, use an in-memory database:

```
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder().UseInMemoryDatabase("YourInMemoryDbName").Options;
```

You can then use this `options` object to create your context instance.

Populate your in-memory database with your sample records prior to running the test.

You can [read more about it here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.inmemorydbcontextoptionsextensions.useinmemorydatabase?devlangs=csharp&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemoryDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseInMemoryDatabase)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=efcore-7.0).

It should be pointed out that this kind of testing is discouraged, mainly because of the differences between the implementations of the In-Memory database and a real MS SQL instance.

You already have a repository abstraction on top of the context so mocking the repos should suffice for your testing purposes. If you find yourself needing to unit test your repos, then it's time to take a step back and review your code as repos should be pretty dumb and only implement logic needed to access the data store.